# Prove that there are unique values $w,b$ such that $L_2(w,b) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}(wx_i + b - y_i)^2$ is minimized.

Tags: proof-writing, least-squares, linear-regression

I would like to prove following result:

> Suppose we have pair of points $D = \{(x_1,x_1),\cdots,(x_n,y_n)\}$. At least two of these points do not overlap (meaning that there is at least one pair of points $(x_j,y_j), (x_i,y_i)$ such that either $x_j≠x_i$ or $y_j ≠ y_i$)
>   Show that there are unique values for $w,b$ such that $L_2(w,b) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}(wx_i + b - y_i)^2$ is minimized.

I've tried to approach the problem using partial derivatives, namely:

1. Find $\frac{\partial L_2}{dw}$, $\frac{\partial L_2}{db}$
2. Set both to zero
3. Try to show that solution for $w,b$ is unique.

However, the approach has led me nowhere.

So how can I prove the result above?

---

I've seen similar [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/363144/why-does-the-l2-norm-loss-have-a-unique-solution-and-the-l1-norm-loss-have-possi) on the Cross Validated, but here I'm more intrested in the proof, instead of the intuitive explanation.

Comment: Use the strict convexity of $L_2(w,b)$.

Comment: I would guess the strict convexity of $L_2$ is what needs to be shown. OP, to be clear, is the issue finding the minimum or proving that it's unique?

Comment: @CharlesHudgins Proving that it is unique.

Comment: Then it is as @Cesareo said. Prove that $L_2$ is strictly convex. Then prove that strictly convex functions on convex sets have at most one minimum.

Comment: I am unsure about your definition of "do not overlap". As written, it looks more like "are distinct", which is a given when we consider $D$ as a set.

Comment: @HagenVonEitzen I was unsure what was the proper mathematical term for those points, so I went with "do not overlap". But I mentioned what I meant by "not overlapping", namely one pair of points $(x_j,y_j), (x_i,y_i)$ such that either $x_j≠x_i$ or $y_j ≠ y_i$

Answer (score 1):

The problem statement allows all $x_i=0$ as long as all $y_i$ are distinct.
In such a case, $L_2(w,b)$ does not depend on $w$ and hence the claim is false.

**Concrete example:** $n=2$, $(x_1,y_1)=(0,\pi)$, $(x_1,y_2)=(0,42)$.